# MVC 5 Facebook login access denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, facebook-login, access-denied

I'm trying to setup Facebook login on my website (MVC 5) but I have an issue that seems I cannot overcome for a couple of days already.

Everything works perfect on localhost but when deploying to testing environment or production it doesn't work. I keep getting "[http://stage.automasy.com/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?error=access_denied#*=*](http://stage.automasy.com/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?error=access_denied#_=_)" and I don't understand why.

I configured everything in facebook developer account, the app is showing green.

This is part of my code:

In Startup.Auth:

```
var options = new    Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AppId = "xxx",
                AppSecret = "xxx",
                CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-facebook"),
                BackchannelHttpHandler = new   Services.FacebookBackChannelHandler(),
                UserInformationEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name"
            };

            options.Provider = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                    foreach (var claim in context.User)
                    {
                        var claimType = string.Format("urn:facebook:{0}", claim.Key);
                        string claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();
                        if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue, "XmlSchemaString", "Facebook"));

                    }
                    return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            };
            options.SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie;
            options.Scope.Add("email");
            options.Scope.Add("public_profile");

            app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options);
```

and in AccountController:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
```

I'm out of ideas...so if someone can help me I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar problem. As soon as I don't set the Provider, CallbackPath, BackchannelHttpHandler and UserInformationEndpoint it works. But I still have no access to the Claims...

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue.
Eventually I fixed this by upgrading the Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook (to version 3.1.0; in the default VS2015 MVC project 3.0.1 is embedded at the time of writing).

Run this in the Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook
```